# Spring Data Rest + Spring Security without Spring boot does work?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-data-rest

I am trying fire up my app where I use spring data rest and spring security without Spring Boot. But I could make Spring Security works. All security beans are created but when I send a request it doesn't go through security filter chain, but directly to the controller method.

What might be wrong with my configuration? What have I missed?

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.demo.gallery"})
@Import({MongoConfig.class})
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertiesPropertySource() throws IOException {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer source = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        ResourcePropertySource propertySource = new ResourcePropertySource("classpath:application.properties");
        MutablePropertySources propertySources = new MutablePropertySources();
        propertySources.addFirst(propertySource);
        source.setPropertySources(propertySources);
        return source;
    }
}
```

_

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{AppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
        super.customizeRegistration(registration);
        String userHome = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
        File bannersDir = Paths.get(userHome, ".gallery/banners").toFile();
        if (!bannersDir.exists()) {
            if (!bannersDir.mkdirs()) {
                throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Could create %s directory", bannersDir));
            }
        }
        registration.setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement(userHome));
    }
}
```

_

```
    @EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.demo.gallery.persistence.repository")
    public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
    
        private final String dbName;
        private final String host;
        private final int port;
    
        public MongoConfig(@Value("${db.name}") String dbName,
                           @Value("${db.host}") String host,
                           @Value("${db.port}") int port) {
            this.dbName = dbName;
            this.host = host;
            this.port = port;
        }
    
        @Override
        protected String getDatabaseName() {
            return dbName;
        }
    
        @Override
        public MongoClient mongoClient() {
            return new MongoClient(host, port);
        }
    
        @Override
        protected Collection<String> getMappingBasePackages() {
            return Collections.singleton("com.demo.gallery.persistence.model");
        }
    }
```

_

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AppUserRepository appUserRepository;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(AppUserRepository appUserRepository) {
        this.appUserRepository = appUserRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return email -> {
            AppUser appUser = appUserRepository.findByEmail(email);
            List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = appUser.getRoles().stream()
                .map(Enum::name)
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return new User(appUser.getEmail(), appUser.getPassword(), authorities);
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }
}
```

_

```
@Configuration
@Import({RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class, SecurityConfig.class})
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    public ResourceProcessor<Resource<Ad>> personProcessor() {
        return new ResourceProcessor<Resource<Ad>>() {
            @Override
            public Resource<Ad> process(Resource<Ad> resource) {
                String baseUri = BasicLinkBuilder.linkToCurrentMapping().toString();
                Link bannerLink = new Link(new UriTemplate(baseUri + "/api/ads/banner/{id}")
                    .with("id", TemplateVariable.VariableType.PATH_VARIABLE), "banner")
                    .expand(Collections.singletonMap("id", resource.getContent().getId()));
                resource.add(bannerLink);
                return resource;
            }
        };
    }


    @Bean
    public RepositoryRestConfigurer repositoryRestConfigurer() {
        return RepositoryRestConfigurer.withConfig(config -> {
            config.setBasePath("/api");
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my *build.gradle* file:

```
plugins {
    id 'war'
    id 'net.ltgt.apt' version '0.10'
    id "org.akhikhl.gretty" version "2.0.0"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone'
    }
}

gretty {
    httpPort = 8558
    contextPath = '/'
}

group 'com.demo'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

ext {
    lombockVersion = '1.16.20'
    servletapiVersion = '4.0.0'
    junitVersion = '4.12'
    springTestVersion = '5.0.5.RELEASE'
    springDataMongodbVersion = '2.1.0.M2'
    springDataRestWebMvcVersion = '3.1.0.M2'
    log4jVersion = '1.2.17'
    slf4jVersion = '1.7.25'
    logbackVersion = '1.2.3'
    springSecurityVersion = '5.0.5.RELEASE'
}

dependencies {
    compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:${logbackVersion}"
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombockVersion}"
    apt "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombockVersion}"
    testCompile "junit:junit:${junitVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-test:${springTestVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:${springDataMongodbVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:${springDataRestWebMvcVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:${springSecurityVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:${springSecurityVersion}"
    providedCompile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:${servletapiVersion}"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Security filter registration seems to be missing.
You need to map the `springSecurityFilterChain` You can easily do this by extending `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` and optionally overriding methods to customize the mapping.

Refer the below spring guide.
[Spring Security Java Config Preview: Web Security](https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/)

Answer (score 1):

Here are a useful links additionally to @narayan-sambireddy's ones:

1. [Hello Web Security Java Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer).
2. [Related topic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447603/abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer-vs-abstractannotationconfigdispatcher)